# error replacing rows of `matrix` by `Matrix`

Tags: r, matrix

I came across this unexpected behavior of the `Matrix` package when
replacing rows of a `matrix` object by a `Matrix` object. Here is a minimal example illustrating the issue:

```
library(Matrix)
m1 = matrix(1:6, 3, 2)    # 3x2 matrix
M1 = Matrix(1:6, 3, 2)    # 3x2 Matrix
m2 = matrix(11:14, 2, 2)  # 2x2 matrix
M2 = Matrix(11:14, 2, 2)  # 2x2 Matrix
```

I replace the first two rows of the 3x2 matrix by the 2x2 matrix:

```
m1[1:2, ] = m2
m1[1:2, ] = as.matrix(M2)
M1[1:2, ] = M2
# all ok

m1[1:2, ] = M2
# Error in m1[1:2, ] = M2 :
# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

In my opinion, this should not throw an error. The operation is dimensionally consistent after all. At least the error message is misleading.

Strangely `m1[1:2, 1] = M2[, 1]` does not throw an error.

Comment: How did you specify which elements should be placed in which index?

Comment: There is difference between a normal matrix object and a `dgeMatrix` object. First. `dgeMatrix` object contain various elements within it that can be accessed using the `@` operator. ie try doing `M2@` and then press the `TAB` key, you will see all the elements in the `dgeMatrix` matrix. or rather you can try `unclass(M2)` . so unless you change the class to matrix by `as.matrix` or unless you subset a part of it with `[` it will be difficult for it to operate with a normal matrix

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara If that were the problem, the first three should fail as well, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Onyambu I see what you mean. By the same logic, shouldn't the last example, where only the first column is replaced, also throw an error?

Comment: i responded to this saying that it wont throw an errow. By subsetting, you get back a vector.. not a dgeMatrix object. vectors are the building block of a matrix..

Comment: @Onyambu Yes that makes sense, thank you